# Write text to file function python

Tags: python-3.x

so I would like to ask you for help.
I was scooping and sweeping the internet so long for that and I did not find how to do it. What I just produced is totally wrong and my professor did bad time with formulating the task. it is entry level task on university I have already finished the hardest ones, but this one I just dont get what he wants

Translation is made by me so it might be little bit off, but bear with me, please.

"Create file "linewriter.py". This file will have function writeTextToFile, that will accept one parameter and on end is also one parameter. Function will take the parameter on input and chain it with variable STATIC_TEXT (stated bellow). Queue of chaining will be as follows: 1st static text and then argument of function. This way chained input will write to file of any given name   and a the name of this file will be returned as input parameter of function.

STATIC_TEXT: “This is my static text which must be added to file. It is very long text and I do not know what they want to do with this terrible text. ”

...
What? I really don't get what he want's from me. Can you help? Thank you all :)

Comment: You say what you produced it totally wrong? Why was it wrong?

Comment: well i tryed to ... I got in middle of writing response idea and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

```
STATICKY_TEXT = "This is my static text which must be added to file. It is very long text and I do not know what they want to do with this terrible text.\nNew Line! "
saveFile = open ("exampleFile.txt","w")
saveFile.write(STATICKY_TEXT)
saveFile.close()
```

solved it :) but I COULD not figure it out for days haha ... silly me